# TextFormField input messed up in Flutter Web (Google's built in browser on Android)

Tags: flutter

I get very messed up input when typing some combinations of characters, like an email address:

[image]

Here's the code for the field:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
  controller: email,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
)
```

This happens when I open the app in Google's built-in browser in Google chat or Gmail. It also happens if I "install" the app to the home screen from a chrome browser. Is there a fix for this or is flutter web just too immature to be used in production at this point (I can't really force users to use chrome, especially when sending links in mail or chat would be a way to get users)?

Input looks fine when typing the address in a chrome browser (i.e. type in the address, not use one that was saved to the desktop).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it by forcing using canvas kit renderer like so:

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

You can add it to your `index.html` file

```
renderer: "canvaskit",
```

You can read more about how to implement it here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers